# Writing a partial differential in the text

Tags: symbols

Does anyone know how to write a partial differential symbol, but in the text not as part of an equation?

Thanks

Comment: `$\partial$` should do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is an inline $\partial$
\end{document}
```